# StackExchange pop-up and user page data to sync "read" status

Tags: feature-request

I note the red circle on the top-left of the page that says I have messages waiting in my in-box.  I diligently read each.  I then click on my name, click on the responses tab, and see the same messages highlighted as unread.  It'd be nice if reading the message from "responses" would also mark it read in the StackExchange popup and vice-versa.